# How to get check box values in an array

Tags: javascript, php, checkbox

how to make array from values checked from multiple check box and send it to another file using Ajax .
Also how can the checked value be removed from array when uncheck is performed on any previously checked box.
Please help to do this using javascript.
Below is whole form function arranged.Also i am able to send values for date,moth and year but not able to do same for selected time.

```
<script>
function loadXMLDoc()

{

    var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("containerG").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
var date=document.getElementById("fdate).value;
var month=document.getElementById("fmonth").value;
var year=document.getElementById("fyear").value;
var year=document.getElementById("time").value;

var url ="selectedGraph.php?currentdate="+date"&currentmonth"+month"&currentyear="+year"&currenttime="+selectedtime;

alert("url");
}
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Below is check box function-:

```
<?php function drop() { ?>

<div style="border:2px solid #ccc; width:130px; height: 100px; overflow-y: scroll;">
<input type="checkbox" name="multiple[]" value="01">1-2 Hours</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="multiple[]" value="02">2-3 Hours</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="multiple[]" value="03">3-4 Hours</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="multiple[]" value="04">4-5 Hours</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="multiple[]" value="05">5-6 Hours</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="multiple[]" value="06">6-7 Hours</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="multiple[]" value="07">7-8 Hours</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="multiple[]" value="08">8-9 Hours</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="multiple[]" value="09">9-10 Hours</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="multiple[]" value="10">10-11 Hours</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="multiple[]" value="11">11-12 Hours</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="multiple[]" value="12">12-13 Hours</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="multiple[]" value="13">13-14 Hours</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="multiple[]" value="14">14-15 Hours</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="multiple[]" value="15">15-16 Hours</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="multiple[]" value="16">16-17 Hours</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="multiple[]" value="17">17-18 Hours</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="multiple[]" value="18">18-19 Hours</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="multiple[]" value="19">19-20 Hours</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="multiple[]" value="20">20-21 Hours</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="multiple[]" value="21">21-22 Hours</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="multiple[]" value="22">22-23 Hours</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="multiple[]" value="23">23-24 Hours</input>
</div>
<?php }?>

<?php
echo "From: "; date_dropdown('from'); month_dropdown('from'); year_dropdown('from');      drop();?>
```

Comment: what do you have so far?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: need some help on this please help me out..

Comment: I would look into a foreach loop, this would probably be best. You would loop through each of the entries and could form an array or a string, depending on your needs. Without seeing any working example, it is hard to pinpoint where you are and where you are going, or even to suggest alternative methods.